# Detect if number input tried to be above max

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I have some third-party jQuery plugins that are binding events to a button with specific class.

I need to bind another event, but these events needs to be executed BEFORE any other events.

For example:

I have this structure:

```html
<input type="button" class="minus" value="-" />
<input type="number" class="qty" value="5" min="1" max="10" />
<input type="button" class="plus" value="+" />
```

The `minus` and `plus` buttons decrease and increase the value on `qty`. But another script that I don't have access is handling this.

I need to add an event to these buttons, BUT my event needs to come before the default action (increase or decrease).

```js
jQuery(".woocommerce").on("click", "input[type='button'].plus", function(){
    var value = jQuery(this).parent().find("input.qty").val();
    var max = jQuery(this).parent().find("input.qty").attr("max");

    if(value >= max){
    alert("Can't add more items.");
        return;
    }
});

jQuery(".woocommerce").on("click", "input[type='button'].minus", function(){
    var value = jQuery(this).parent().find("input.qty").val();
    var min = jQuery(this).parent().find("input.qty").attr("max");

    if(value <= min){
        alert("Can't remove more items.");
        return;
    }
});
```

Considering that I can't change the order scripts are queued in my page, how can I prioritize my event?

Comment: Would it be feasible to add a 'change' event handler to the number input and handle things there? It won't fire before the other events but it will give you an opportunity to check the value,

Comment: @whoshotdk - I thought the same, but when an input value is changed programmatically, the `change` event doesn't fire.

Comment: Ah my bad, I did not test. You're absolutely right.